# Sinon mock is calling the real method

Tags: node.js, jestjs, sinon

I want to mock a method on a class so that a dummy method is called which I can obtain stats on such as how many time it was invoked etc...

I'm trying to do it this way using Sinon, but the actual method is still invoked (and verify isn't registering the call)

I'm using Sinon with Jest ... yes I know Jest has it's own mocking /stubbing/spying capabilities but I've been having trouble with them in Node so I'm looking at Sinon. I can't use Mocha instead of jest which usually pairs with Sinon (sigh, corporate).

**Test**

```
    const sinon = require('sinon')
    const Cache = require('../../../adapters/Cache')
    const Fizz = require('../Fizz')

    describe('CACHE', () => {
      it('should return a   mock', () => {
        const mockCache = sinon.mock(Cache.prototype, 'retrieveRecords')
        const fizz = new Fizz()
        fizz.doStuff()
        mockCache.expects('retrieveRecords').once()
        mockCache.verify()
      })
    })
```

**Fizz**

```
const Cache = require('../../adapters/Cache')
const Thing = require('../../adapters/Thing')

class Fizz {
    doStuff() {
        const thing = new Thing()
        const cache = new Cache()

        return cache.retrieveRecords('foo')
    }
}
module.exports = Fizz
```

Comment: I got my syntax wrong. This works:

Answer (score 0):

I got my syntax wrong. Needed to call `mockCache.expects('retrieveRecords')` to make it not call the real method, I was thinking this counted the invocations, but that's what I get from not RTFM. This works:

```
const sinon = require('sinon')
    const Cache = require('../../../adapters/Cache')
    const Fizz = require('../Fizz')

    describe('CACHE', () => {
      it('should return a   mock', () => {
        const mockCache = sinon.mock(Cache.prototype)
        const expectation = mockCache.expects("retrieveRecords")
        expectation.once()
        const fizz = new Fizz()
        const res = fizz.doStuff()
        mockCache.verify()
      })
    })
```